# How to customise a HSlider in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm new to flex,and I want to change the image of HSlider,like this

[image]

What should I do?please give me a simple example.

Comment: I think this is a great question if you just change the title to "How does one skin components in flex".  HSlider is a great example of skinning because it isn't simple, nor is it overly complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom skin. Now, HSlider is a little bit special in that it has some subcomponents that are also skinnable. You'll actually have to create three custom skins:

- one for the HSlider itself (this skin includes the tooltip)
- one for the track (the yellow/brown zone in your picture)
- and one for the thumb

The track and the thumb are both in fact Buttons so those skins will have to be Button skins.

Explaining the entire process will make this answer too lengthy and specific, so I'll just get you started. You should be able to figure it out from there. I'll also assume you're using FlashBuilder as an IDE.

**Create main skin**

Set the `skinClass` style on an `HSlider` and hit Alt+Space. This will bring up code completion, but you can also select "Create Skin...".

[image]

Select that and a wizard will appear. Fill out something like the following. Note that we're making a copy of the default Spark HSlider skin. We remove the styling code because it will not be necessary in such a customized skin.

[image]

**Create track and thumb skins**

Open this new skin class and scroll down to the bottom. You'll see two `Button`s; one with id `track` and one with id `thumb`. Their skinClass style is set to the default spark skins for these buttons. Delete the content and repeat the operation of the previous step (creating a new skin), only this time create a copy of `HSliderTrackSkin` and `HSliderThumbSkin`

**Edit the skins**

You now have an exact copy of the default Spark skins for HSlider (except you removed the styling). Now you can start editing: changing colors, changing shapes, etc. If you need more information about Flex graphics, I suggest you Google up on FXG. But you can just try to fiddle with the default skins and see where you can get too.

Comment: cool!Thank you!I didn't know that HSlider have subcomponents.

Answer (score 12):

@RIAstar had a great answer. But there is a little problem - this orange part before thumb. AFAIK the easiest way to create skin like this is to add rect or more complicated figure in HSlider skin, that will change it's width according to thumb's x coordinate, i.e.

```
<s:Button id="track" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minWidth="33" width="100" 
          tabEnabled="false"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin" />

<s:Rect width="{thumb.x + thumb.width/2}" height="{track.height}">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x00FF00" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Button id="thumb" top="0" bottom="0" width="11" height="11" 
          tabEnabled="false"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin" />
```